# Logical snail along a straight line

Tags: combinatorics

A snail crawled along a straight line for 6 minutes while separate people watched its progress. Each of these people watched snail for  1 minute and during this minute the snail rolled exactly by one foot. It is known that the snail was always watched by at least one person. What is the maximum possible distance the snail could crawl during the 6 minutes?
I tried thinking about sum of overlapped time which turns out to be total number of people - 6. But it was of no help. I think the answer is 6 feet and tried to prove by contradiction but couldn't.

Comment: I also doubt the following proof: let's say only 6 people watched the snail as it moved for 6 seperate minutes, so snail travelled 6 ft. But if we added another person he will just overcount snails progress.

Comment: Unless it's a trick question the answer is obviously 6. I don't even see what there is to do.  They just took turns watching and switched during some infinitesimal amount of time epsilon for a total of 6 minutes = 6 feet. Am I missing something?

Comment: I also think the same but  It was only during the time  they watched when the snail moved a foot,and they are not switching they are watching together as many people could be there

Comment: actually it  can crawl for a lot more - nearly twice (12 feet), of course the snail in question is assumed a super-snail (at least with regards to its acceleration abilities).

Comment: can you elaborate further

Comment: Can you see why it could move 2 feet in 61 seconds? If you progress a bit on this I could then elaborate.

Comment: No, I don't get it

Comment: `Is it because it has to be watched by 2 observers

Comment: How many people are watching the snail move?

Comment: At least 6 people are watching

Comment: @https://math.stackexchange.com/users/729993/shortmanikos thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is someone watching the snail for the first minute of the period, and someone watching the snail for the last minute, the maximum snail movement is $10$ feet.

The pattern for this is that the snail moves one foot to start with, then stops for a while (with two people watching the pause), then moves two feet - in the middle of which the watcher changes, and so on through the time period. The final minute can only see one foot of movement by the assumption that there is a watcher for that whole period. (If you allow an initial and final watcher to count their minute of watching outside the six minute period, you can squeeze in two more feet of movement, but that's not how I read the setup).

To minimize the snail speed during the dashes, you can allow $12$ seconds for each foot travelled (each green block in the image is a foot of travel), with the pauses lasting 48 seconds.

[image]